# Varnish redirect loop

Tags: nginx, redirect, varnish, redirection, 301-redirect

I've tried with a lot of varnish configurations and always experience the same redirect loop, after varnish is running for a couple of hours some pages are displaying the message: `The page isn't redirecting properly` in firefox. [image]

As the image shows, the first request return a 301 status code, the rest are 302, I have no idea from where this 302 status code are, in my nginx config I have:

```
# We don't want someone to visit a default site via IP
# So we catch all non-defined Hosts or blank hosts here
# the default listen will cause this server block to be used
# when no matching hostname can be found in other server blocks
server {
    # use default instead for nginx 0.7.x, default_server for 0.8.x+
    listen 81 default_server;
    # if no listen is specified, all IPv4 interfaces on port 80 are listened to
    # to listen on both IPv4 and IPv6 as well, listen [::] and 0.0.0.0 must be specified. 
    server_name _;
    return 301 $scheme://elbauldelprogramador.com$request_uri;
}
```

In sites-enabled/mysite:

```
server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:81;
    server_name www.elbauldelprogramador.com;
    return 301 $scheme://elbauldelprogramador.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:81;
    server_name elbauldelprogramador.com

    #rest of configuration
}
```

Maybe those 301 redirect are the problem?, My current varnish config is this (Although it happens with all config I had prove.)

```
# Enter your backend Wordpress site here.
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1"; # XXX CHANGE THIS
    .port = "81";        # (and maybe this)
    .connect_timeout = 60s;
    .first_byte_timeout = 60s;
    .between_bytes_timeout = 60s;
    .max_connections = 800;
}   

acl purge {
    "127.0.0.1";
}

# Drop any cookies sent to Wordpress.
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.request == "PURGE") {
        if (!client.ip ~ purge) {
            error 405 "Not allowed.";
        }
        return (lookup);
    }

    if (req.http.host ~ "(?i)^(www.)?elbauldelprogramador.com") {
        set req.http.host = "elbauldelprogramador.com";
    }

    # Normalize encoding
    if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
        if (req.url ~ "\.(jpg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg)$") {
            # No point in compressing these
            remove req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
        } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
        } else {
            # unknown algorithm
            remove req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        }
    }
    if (!(req.url ~ "wp-(login|admin|cron)")) {
        unset req.http.cookie;
    }
}

# Drop any cookies Wordpress tries to send back to the client.
sub vcl_fetch {
    if (!(req.url ~ "wp-(login|admin)")) {
        unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
    }
}

sub vcl_hit {
    if (req.request == "PURGE") {
        purge;
        error 200 "Purged.";
    }
}

sub vcl_miss {
    if (req.request == "PURGE") {
        purge;
        error 200 "Purged.";
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the `Location` being sent with the 302?  What content or application is Varnish in front of (since that's where the 302s are coming from)?

Comment: I have nginx behind varnish on port 81, but in my config I do not have any 302 redirections, neither nginx or varnish are sending 302. After the first request, with 301 redirect, the url is http://domain.com/original-request-url/404. I do not know if for `Location` you mean this. Thank you

Comment: What application is running within nginx?  `Location` is the HTTP header sent with the 30x responses, it's visible in your image but for the `301` only (and not the complete URL).

Comment: Wordpress, the Location header for the 301 is http://elbauldelprogramador.com/crear-formularios-en-django-partir-de-un-modelo-con-modelform/ and for the rest is http://elbauldelprogramador.com/crear-formularios-en-django-partir-de-un-modelo-con-modelform/404

Comment: Is `http://elbauldelprogramador.com/crear-formularios-en-django-partir-de-un-modelo-con-modelform/` a valid page if you hit wordpress directly?  Wordpress is apparently trying to redirect to some kind of 404 page.

Comment: Yes it is, currently I have been disabled varnish, but that page exits. It is strange, because not always happens in a specific URL, some times the redirect loop happens at /robots.txt, other times in other URL.

Comment: Does the working page include that trailing slash?

Comment: If a request does not have a trailing slash a 301 redirect is perform, but I think this is common to all wordpress installations.